# JQuery UI AutoComplete inserts <br> after select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI AutoComplete in a content editable div. I am encountering an issue where a `<br>`-tag is inserted after I select a value from the autocomplete dropdown and I type something in the end of the `<div>`.

The steps to reproduce are:

1. Write something
2. Select something from the autocomplete dropdown
3. Place cursor at end of content editable div
4. Insert a space

This results in a `<br>` tag being inserted at the end of the `<div>`. How can I prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/qf5L0d27/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="main" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid black;width:300px;height:200px"></div>

<script>
    $("div").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response){
            response(['test1', 'test2']);
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
            el = $("div#main");
            old_content = el.html();
            extra_content = ui.item.value;
            el.html(old_content + extra_content);
            el.autocomplete("destroy");
            return false;
        }
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be a problem with autocomplete.

A contenteditable div inserts a `<br>` or `&nbsp;` depending on the browser at the end if it loses and regains focus.